# Access Query sort of Linked tables

Tags: ms-access, query-builder, query-performance, linked-tables

I'm using Access 2007. I have two tables, first one has a PK (primary key), but the second has not.

When using a query linking the two tables on the PK, I need the rows have the same sort as it is in the second table (means as records has been entered), but this doesn't happen by default, I don't know why!

[image: Tables at the left side, Query and its result at the right side.]

Answer (score 1):

Tables are just a big bucket that holds data. There is no order to them unless you supply it. Therefore, in order for the items in your query/table to appear in the order that they were entered you will have to supply something that allows Access to apply this sorting for you.

You should add an AutoNumber Primary Key to the DataSub table. This will automatically increase every time that you add new data to this table, and so you can then use this in any queries to sort by.

Regards,